# Get a specific character and swap columns in a file

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to get 20th character of each line, if its `b` then exchange last 2 columns with each other values AND if its `B` then 3rd last column and last column's value should be exchanged, like shown below.

Sample of input:

```
1234567891011121314b abcd erfg ijkl 12114353 blabla
1234567891011121314Babcd erfg ijkl 12114353 blabla
```

Sample of expected output:

```
1234567891011121314b abcd erfg ijkl blabla 12114353
123456789101112131Babcd erfg blabla 12114353 ijkl
```

I tried following code:

```
while read value
do
    echo "$value" | cut -c20
done < "file"
```

I also tried to use `awk`'s `substr` but couldn't proceed too much in it too.

Actual file is same like shown sample above; please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  val=substr($0,20,1)
}
val=="b"{
  temp=$(NF-1)
  $(NF-1)=$NF
  $NF=temp
  temp=""
}
val=="B"{
  temp=$(NF-2)
  $(NF-2)=$NF
  $NF=temp
  temp=""
}
1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  val=substr($0,20,1)   ##getting 20th character value here.
}
val=="b"{               ##Checking condition if val is b then do following.
  temp=$(NF-1)          ##Creating temp with 2nd last field value here.
  $(NF-1)=$NF           ##Setting last field value to 2nd last field here.
  $NF=temp              ##Again setting last field as temp.
  temp=""               ##Nullifying temp here.
}
val=="B"{               ##Checking condition if val is B then do following.
  temp=$(NF-2)          ##Creating temp which has 3rd last field value here.
  $(NF-2)=$NF           ##Setting 3rd last field value to last field here.
  $NF=temp              ##Again setting last field as temp.
  temp=""               ##Nullifying temp here.
}
1                       ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `AWK` for that task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
12345678910111213141b abcd erfg ijkl 12114353 blabla
12345678910111213141Babcd erfg ijkl 12114353 blabla
```

then

```
awk '{lastcol=$NF}/^.{20}b/{$NF=$(NF-1);$(NF-1)=lastcol}/^.{20}B/{$NF=$3;$3=lastcol}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
12345678910111213141b abcd erfg ijkl blabla 12114353
12345678910111213141Babcd erfg blabla 12114353 ijkl
```

Explanation: for every line store last column content as `lastcol`, if line startswith 20 of any characters followed by `b` then set content of last row to what is 2nd from end column and content of 2nd from end column to `lastcol`, if line startswith 20 of any characters folllowed by `B` then set content of last column to what is in 3rd column and content of 3rd column to `lastcol`. `print` such line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the long way using your current approach, you can use `sed` to finish it off.

Simply check what the 20th character is, and do the appropriate swap in either case using a `sed` substitution. The swap is achieved using 2 or 3 capture groups, depending on which case the line satisfies.

```
file='file.txt'

while read -r value
do
    b=$(echo "$value" | cut -c20)
    if [ "$b" = 'b' ]
    then
        echo "$value" | sed -E 's/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)\s*$/\2 \1/'
    elif [ "$b" = 'B' ]
    then
        echo "$value" | sed -E 's/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)\s*$/\3 \2 \1/'
    fi
done < "$file"
```

This assumes your fields are space-delimited.

In both cases, we anchor the match to the end of the line, and also account for potential trailing whitespace (which we don't bother substituting back in - but you can if you want to).

Output:

```
1234567891011121314b abcd erfg ijkl blabla 12114353
1234567891011121314Babcd erfg blabla 12114353 ijkl
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```sh
perl -lpe 's/^.{19}([bB]).*?\K(\s+\S+)(\s+\S+)(\s+\S+)$/$1 eq "b" ? "$2$4$3" : "$4$3$2"/e'
```

- `^.{19}([bB]).*?\K` capture the 20th character (only if it is `b` or `B`) and ignore all text except last three columns
- `e` flag allows Perl code in replacement section
- `$1 eq "b"` checks if 20th character is `b`

With `sed` (syntax checked with `GNU sed`, might differ for other implementations), modifying the answer from @costaparas, assuming 20th character is always `b` or `B`

```sh
sed -E '/^.{19}b/ s/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)\s*$/\2 \1/; t; s/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)\s*$/\3 \2 \1/'
```

- `/^.{19}b/` checks if 20th character is `b`

  - if so, swap last two columns and then unconditionally start next cycle by using `t` command
- Otherwise, perform the second substitution

  - add `/^.{19}B/` before the second substitution if needed